# Android Studio Tabhost in scrollview always at top

Tags: scrollview, android-tabhost

I have a tabhost in android studio that is inside a scroll view. The tabhost itself lies underneath some text.
[Here is an image of the xml file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9ISK.jpg)
However, whenever i open the app on a device, the scroll view has the tabhost set at the top so i have to scroll up to see the text that is above it.
Why is this and is there a fix?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `TabHost` is the first view that can request focus. So the work-around is to have another focusable view at the top of the `LinearLayout` within the `ScrollView`.

I used the following `View` for this purpose

```
    <View android:focusableInTouchMode="true" android:layout_width="0px" android:layout_height="0px"/>
```

Note: I was heavily inspired by [TabHost inside a ScrollView forces it it to scroll to the bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9826130/tabhost-inside-a-scrollview-forces-it-it-to-scroll-to-the-bottom#10442368) and [Stop EditText from gaining focus at Activity startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555109/stop-edittext-from-gaining-focus-at-activity-startup).